# WCF browser calls return response but client calls doesnt

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf, rest, web-config

I am using wcf rest service in my project. I changed my server and my services dont return any response. When i trying on my web browser services work, but client requests dont. Please help me.
I am using IIS 7 on server side,
Javascript for request
Java for android
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the client service call refer to new server location?

Comment: yeah yeah called new service location. My services dont have any Auth contents. Maybe is it problem?